# Can I ActiveSupport::Concern object be used a helper as well as extending controller functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have functions that return true/false for user permissions (basically a wrapper for certain session variables). I would like the functions available to build menus in the view layer as well within the controllers. Is there any drawbacks in doing this? (Example below)

```
module SecurityPermissions
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def has_this_permissions

  end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include SecurityPermissions
  helper SecurityPermissions
end
```

Comment: For clarification: your question is 'how can I build menu in controller'? You shouldn't build any kind of html in controllers because they are created not for this

Comment: No basically I want to expose the authorization functions in the views and controllers so basically I build the menus without the options the user doesn't have access to, and in the controller to prevent URL hacking. I would build the menu in the view

Answer (score 0):

Although it is tempting to add everything in the view layer and the controller, it is still recommended that you don't do this. The idea is that the view should not concern about the logic. As much as possible, the view should only render something. Using decorators or page objects will help you abstract these out of your view context.

As for the controller, taking out "action" logic to a service would be my favourite way of simplifying everything. Controllers should not concern about how a model should be updated but it should now what to update.

Comment: Do how to I build menus without options the user has access to without that logic?